# How to upload image in a specific folder php?

Tags: php, file, directory

I have xampp installed and I have a program that you choose a file and it gets uploaded to my server. I have a folder in htdocs called uploads thats meant for storing the pictures. When I upload them, it goes in the htdocs, but not the folder in htdocs i want. I did specify that i needed it to go there. Can someone help?

Heres the code:

```
<?php
@$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
@$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
@$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
@$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
if (isset($name)) {
    if (!empty($name)) 
    {
    $location = 'uploads/';
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location. $name));
    echo 'Uploaded';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Please choose a file';
    }

}
?>


<form action="first.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Never use `@` to suppress warnings / errors during debugging. You should at least check whether `$_FILES['file']` is null or not.

Comment: What folder is the script in?

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top -- are you getting any warnings?

Comment: Specify absolute path here, $location = 'uploads/';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code:
 Note: Make sure your `uploads` folder have write permission.

```
<?php
define("DOC_ROOT", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/");
define("PDF_UPLOADS", DOC_ROOT."uploads/");

$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if (isset($name)) 
{
    if (!empty($name)) 
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, PDF_UPLOADS. $name))
            echo 'Uploaded';
        else
            echo "Not Uploaded";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Please choose a file';
    }

}
?>
```