# Multi-fields form with image input

Tags: php, forms, image, pdo, submit

I have a form like this and I would like to know if there is a way to add an image input and upload it to the server.

I would like to be able to upload images to [ROOT]/upload_img/ but, to be honest I don't know how to do it and most of the code parts I found don't work with mine...

Se here I am.

Here's my code :

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="login">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <label>Titre de l'annonce :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="i_title" id="name" required="required" placeholder=""/>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <label>Adresse : </label>
                    <input type="text" name="i_adress" id="email" required="required" placeholder=""/>
                    <br/>
                    <br />
                    <label>Ville :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="i_city" id="city" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Your City"/>
                    <br/>
                    <br />
                    <label>Surface du logement entier :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="i_surf_room" id="surf_room" required="required" placeholder=""/> En m2
                    <br/>
                    <br />
                    <label>Surface de la chambre :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="i_surf_home" id="surf_home" required="required" placeholder=""/>
                    <br/>
                    <br />
                    <label>Description :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="i_description" id="description" required="required" placeholder=""/>
                    <br/>
                    <br />
                    <label>Date de début de disponibilité :</label>
                    <input type="month" name="i_start_date" id="start_date" required="required" placeholder=""/>
                    <br/>
                    <br />
                    <label>Date de fin de disponibilité :</label>
                    <input type="month" name="i_end_date" id="end_date" required="required" placeholder=""/>
                    <br/>
                    <br />
                    <label>Photographies du logement</label>
                    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                        <input type="reset"> - 
                            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
                            <br />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $hostname='xxxx';
    $username='xxxx';
    $password='xxx';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=xxxx",$username,$password);

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
        $sql = "INSERT INTO students (title, adress, city, surf_home, surf_room, description, start_date, end_date)
            VALUES ('".$_POST["i_title"]."','".$_POST["i_adress"]."','".$_POST["i_city"]."','".$_POST["i_surf_home"]."','".$_POST["i_surf_room"]."','".$_POST["i_description"]."','".$_POST["i_start_date"]."','".$_POST["i_end_date"]."')";
        if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
            echo "
                <script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
        } else {
            echo "
                <script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
        }

        $dbh = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This shows how to upload file to a folder.. there could be size limitations, permission issues, timeout considerations.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35356774/3254405

Comment: You forgot to close the first `if`